# Insert MYSQL em Web form C# - Não consigo inserir nada

Tags: c#, mysql, webforms

Estou tentando realizar um insert no meu bd de uma app da faculdade que estou desenvolvendo. Porém, estou tendo dificuldades.

Pegando os valores dos texbox

```
 protected void button1_cad_cliente(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clientes cl = new Clientes();
        cl.Nome = nome_clientes.Text;
        cl.Cpf = Convert.ToInt32(cpf_clientes.Text);
        cl.Rg = Convert.ToInt32(rg.Text);
        cl.Endreco = endereco.Text;
        cl.Email = email_clientes.Text;

        ClienteDAL.cadastra(cl);

    }
```

DAL que realiza o insert ou ao menos essa é a intenção

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Geax.Model;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

 namespace Geax.DAL
 {
public class ClienteDAL
{
    public static void cadastra(Clientes obj)
    {
        Conexao conn1 = new Conexao();
        conn1.AbrirConexao();
        String InsertCliente = ("INSERT INTO tab_cliente (nome,cpf,rg,endereco,telefone,email) VALUES('Cl.Nomes','Cl.Cpf','Cl.Rg','Cl.Endereco','Cl.Telefone','Cl.Email')");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(InsertCliente);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
}
```

Classe que realiza a conexão com o banco:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Geax.DAL
{
public class Conexao
{
private static MySqlConnection objConexao = null;
   private String conn_db = "server=localhost; Database=xpto; User=root;    Password='';";

    public void AbrirConexao()
   {
        objConexao = new MySqlConnection();
        objConexao.ConnectionString = conn_db;
        objConexao.Open();
   } 
 }   
}
```

---

```
    protected void button1_cad_cliente(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clientes cl = new Clientes();
        cl.Nome = nome_clientes.Text;
        cl.Cpf = Convert.ToInt32(cpf_clientes.Text);
        cl.Rg = Convert.ToInt32(rg.Text);
        cl.Endreco = endereco.Text;
        cl.Email = email_clientes.Text;

        ClienteDAL.cadastra(cl);

    }
```

Com já tentei associar o `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", stringComNome);` com os dados que pego acima.

Pus: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome_clientes.txt);` mas não reconhece

Comment: Não realiza o insert e aparece um erro

Comment: Erro que aparece ao tentar inserir: http://i.imgur.com/V03ZJDm.png

Comment: Paulo, no metodo `cadastra(Clientes obj)` você define o `objeto` de `Clientes` com nome `obj`, mas passa a usar `C1.nome`, `C1.cpf`... Não seria esse o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nunca** dispare um SQL desta forma:

```
String InsertCliente = ("INSERT INTO tab_cliente (nome,cpf,rg,endereco,telefone,email) VALUES('Cl.Nomes','Cl.Cpf','Cl.Rg','Cl.Endereco','Cl.Telefone','Cl.Email')");
```

Parametrize **sempre** os valores, mesmo que seja apenas um teste:

```
String InsertCliente = ("INSERT INTO tab_cliente (nome,cpf,rg,endereco,telefone,email) VALUES(@nome, @cpf, @rg, @endereco, @telefone, @email)");

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(InsertCliente);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", stringComNome);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", stringComCpf);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", stringComRg);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", stringComEndereco);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", stringComTelefone);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", stringComEmail);
```

Outra coisa: o bloco de execução deve estar dentro de um `try` pra que vocês possa interceptar exceções se elas ocorrerem:

```
try 
{
    Conexao conn1 = new Conexao();
    conn1.AbrirConexao();
    String InsertCliente = ("INSERT INTO tab_cliente (nome,cpf,rg,endereco,telefone,email) VALUES(@nome, @cpf, @rg, @endereco, @telefone, @email)");

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(InsertCliente);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", stringComNome);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", stringComCpf);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", stringComRg);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", stringComEndereco);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", stringComTelefone);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", stringComEmail);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Outra coisa é que da forma como está, você não está relacionando a conexão com o comando, então nunca vai funcionar. Coloque o comando dentro do bloco de uso de uma conexão:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Database=xpto; User=root;    Password='';")) 
{
    try 
    {
        conn.Open();
        String InsertCliente = ("INSERT INTO tab_cliente (nome,cpf,rg,endereco,telefone,email) VALUES(@nome, @cpf, @rg, @endereco, @telefone, @email)");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = InsertCliente;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", stringComNome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", stringComCpf);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", stringComRg);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", stringComEndereco);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", stringComTelefone);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", stringComEmail);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

O método no final fica assim:

```
public static void Cadastra(Clientes obj)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Database=xpto; User=root;    Password='';")) 
    {
        try 
        {
            conn.Open();
            String InsertCliente = ("INSERT INTO tab_cliente (nome,cpf,rg,endereco,telefone,email) VALUES(@nome, @cpf, @rg, @endereco, @telefone, @email)");

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = InsertCliente;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", obj.Nome);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", obj.Cpf);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", obj.Rg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", obj.Endereco);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", obj.Telefone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", obj.Email);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Só não entendi muito bem essa parte: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", stringComNome);

Como vou associar o 'stringComnome' com os dados que peguei do textbox?

Comment: Você troca `stringComNome` pelo dado do `TextBox`.

Comment: @PauloViníciusMatos Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! :)

Comment: Cigano, continua sem inserir no BD.

Comment: Você colocou breakpoints em algumas linhas pra verificar o qe está sendo feito? A execução retornou erros?

Comment: Não retornou nenhum erro

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17331/discussion-between-paulo-vinicius-matos-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).